# How to force an ajax call with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile.  I would like to navigate from one page to another and force an ajax call.  Right now if I navigate for the first time it will store the pages in the DOM.  Then the next time you go to that sub page it uses what is in the DOM rather than ajaxing it in again.  If I put the following on the links to the other pages then it works on the desktop, but it does not work on the mobile device since the mobile device does not have a "click".

```
<a href="page2.php" data-ajax="true" onclick="$(document.getElementById($(this).attr('href'))).remove();" >link</a>
```

I tried to put this functionality into the head of the document within a jquery function like this with the idea of changing the "click" to "tap" as described in the documentation.

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ( !$this.attr('rel') || $this.attr('rel') != 'external' )
  $(document.getElementById( $this.attr('href') )).remove();
});
```

But this will remove the page after it goes to it.

What I need it to do is remove the page, then load it again.  I found in the documentation that the event [pagebeforechange](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/events.html) but I have not found how or if this would work.

What is the best way to transition from one page to another and force the ajax loading of the page even if the page has been previously view?

Comment: Why are you forcing the ajax call again? There may be a different solution that will give you the same end result your looking for.

Comment: If a page is generated with database information and then the database changes.  I want them to get the updated information if they visit that page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How bout this:

button:

```
<a id="button">link</a>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#button', function(){
    $.mobile.changePage( "page2.php", { reloadPage: true } );
});
```

Update: Changed to a better answer.
Update: Added more for clarity.

Comment: The pages are in separate files.

Comment: I changed answer I should have seen that you were linking to a different page.

Comment: I tested your solution, but it does not seem to be working...  I might have done something wrong.  I will continue to test it.

Comment: What version of Jquery mobile are you using?

Comment: It seems like $(document).on('vclick', '#button', function(){ is not being called.  I did a console.log inside it to see if it was being used when I click on the link and it showed nothing.

Comment: I changed that to $('.forceajax').live('click', function() { and the console.log does show that the function was called.  But something strange is happening.  I go to the page2.php (no ajax reloading) then when I leave the page (click on the back button) it will go back, but then immediately will return to page2.php with the reloading.  It is close to what I want, but without it going immediately back to reload.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9221/discussion-between-codaniel-and-jason)